# How do you encrypt DNS traffic in 2017?

Tags: vpn, dns

I have seen a couple of questions on here today that recommend DNScrypt for encrypting DNS traffic. However, I feel a little bit of gut inertia that this is not good enough for 2017.

What tools do you recommend for encrypting DNS traffic? My real question is... what tools do you use. I really care about safety / ... on the net.

Comment: DNS is a protocol, which means everything connecting to it needs to comply with its standards .... If we use some custom tools or techniques, then it's not DNS anymore ...

Comment: Also, are you talking about DNS as a user or as an admin of a DNS server?

Comment: I am talking about DNS as a user. It seems that not that many people are interested DNSCrypt. Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: The industry recommends using DNScrypt, that's why it is the protocol of choice. Not every DNS admin bothers to set it up and people do not demand its use.

Comment: @schroeder Thank you! I am going to try to set this up on my computers. Thanks for the help! I am really starting to love the community. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I feel a little bit of gut inertia that this is not good enough for 2017

Gut inertia is usually not the best barometer of actual security. :-) But, I understand what you're getting at. You're wondering if something that has been around for a while is strong enough to be safe and secure in the current age of constant hacks, attacks, and breaches. It's a reasonable question, and asking for clarification never hurts.

**The alternatives**

First, DNS is unencrypted by default. So, if you're not running DNS Crypt, or routing your DNS over a VPN, you're basically naked, which (according to the "gut standard" and the *real* standard isn't good enough for 2017.

Yes... even over a VPN. That request is only encrypted until it egresses from the VPN endpoint. Then, it's naked again.

**DNSCrypt Security**

The DNSCrypt protocol is quite good and uses modern cryptography. A session starts with an unencrypted packet, which encodes information about the crypto it has at its disposal (certificates, etc...)

The server responds with *signed* certificates for the client to use. The client then verifies the certs using previously distributed (known-good / trusted) public keys for that provider.

Along with its choice of public key, the client will also choose which key it's going to use based on its own capabilities, and then (according to that cert and its own capabilities) execute a key exchange with the provider (DNS server).

When the encrypted request is made to the provider (DNS server), the client public key and a magic number (that corresponds to the cert the client chose) is transmitted along with the client response.

... and there was much encrypted rejoicing...

This is a very similar pattern to how other forms of crypto establish communication (such as SSL / TLS).

**It authenticates**

The DNSCrypt protocol doesn't just encrypt, it also authenticates. It calls for authentication prior to decryption, which is the correct order of things.

If a request is encrypted, but cannot be authenticated (signature doesn't pan out) the request is quietly discarded.

**It will let you randomize your keys**

The protocol supports short term keys as well as generating a new key for every request, which makes it *very* difficult for any requests or activity to be tracked and logged in terms of requests.

**It's modern**

The DNS Crypt protocol uses elliptic Curve25119 in Montgomery form and hsalsa20 hash for key exchange. This is the same stuff created by [Dan Berstein in his sodium library](https://nacl.cr.yp.to/).

**Where's the weak point?**

As with most crypto, the weakness is in the implementation. OpenDNS, Google, and a few other folks that really know what they are doing can be trusted to do it right.

Setting up your own, or using a random one may not be such a good idea.

Another weak point is logging (does the provider log what it's doing? Do they secure the logs). Also, if the implmentor was using keys that were compromised, that would be an issue as well.

[Reference](https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-proxy/blob/master/DNSCRYPT-V2-PROTOCOL.txt)

Comment: Wow! Your explanation of DNSCrypt is totally exquisite. I think this is the best explanation of DNScrypt on the net. I'm curious if you use DNScrypt. It maybe be a great assumption, but it sounds like you're a big supporter of it with great reason! Amazing stuff here, really amazing.

Comment: Yep. I do. :-) I see you're new here, so, if my answer is satisfactory, please accept / upvote to close it out. Or... You can wait for other answers as well. Up to you. :-)